# 0 or blank for future periods when calculating cumulative amount - Power BI

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-desktop

I need to calculate the actual cumulative payments per a cohort and the 'months since installation'.

For example, here is the data for 2023-2 cohort. As you see, months installed = 0.

[image]

If I use the traditional cumulative sum formula, e.g.

```
am = 
CALCULATE(
    SUM(calc[amount]),
        ALLSELECTED('calc'[Months Installed]),
        'calc'[Months Installed]<= MAX('calc'[Months Installed]),calc[real_or_planned] = "real")
```

The cumulative amount for cohort '2023-2' got extended, even though the max months installed = 0.

[image]

I tried adding the conditions, such as:

```
am = if(sum(calc[amount])=Blank(),Blank(),
CALCULATE(
    SUM(calc[amount]),
        ALLSELECTED('calc'[Months Installed]),
        'calc'[Months Installed]<= MAX('calc'[Months Installed]),calc[real_or_planned] = "real"))
```

but the result is still the same with the cumulative amount getting extended to 'future months installed periods'. What am I doing wrong?